# how to suppress "S3 method overwritten" messages from being printed to user console

Tags: r, package, package-development

I have an R package called `ggstatsplot` (https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/) which relies on a collection of packages that share a few `S3` methods between each other. Therefore, every time the package is loaded, the user is bombarded with messages about this issue, which is not useful for the most users.

```r
> library(ggstatsplot)
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'broom.mixed':
  method      from 
  tidy.gamlss broom
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'car':
  method                          from
  influence.merMod                lme4
  cooks.distance.influence.merMod lme4
  dfbeta.influence.merMod         lme4
  dfbetas.influence.merMod        lme4
```

Is there something I can implement in the package internally to avoid these messages getting printed to the user's console? Maybe something using `.onAttach`?

Comment: As a user I find these warnings very useful. I wouldn't want to have them suppressed because that would make debugging harder. If a user finds these warnings not useful, they can modify their `options` as described in `help("library")` to switch them off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickly looked at the code of the package on GitHub, and to me it seems like some of those functions should be removed from NAMESPACE.

You are using `@importFrom()` however simply adding an "Imports:" declaration in DESCRIPTION and then calling the functions by specifying the namespace, i.e. `package::function` is enough. This way they would not get attached to the namespace and would not conflict with one another.

---

Looked a bit closer, and it seems that the issue is with the packages that you export, not your library itself. So for example simply calling `library(broom.mixed)` produces the conflicts. Since you export some of its import (from `broomExtra`) the same conflicts appear.

Seems like there is an issue about it already on their GitHub: [HERE](https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed/issues/23) so best case would be to issue a pull request to them. Or alternatively - maybe you don't really need to export those functions in the first place.

Comment: I've a similar problem in the `DecomposeR` package [link](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=DecomposeR); the `check.emd` and `inst.pulse` are respectively using functions from `usethis` and `hht`, themselves importing the `cli` and spatstat.geom` packages, both having a different `print.boxx` method. I tried the `package::function` notation, and removed all the `@importFrom` and `@import` lines, but when I use the two functions in the same script, I still have the warning message. Can't I use the functions of these packages (who do not rely on `print.boxx`) in a way preventing any conflict ?

Answer (score 4):

> Therefore, every time the package is loaded, the user is bombarded with messages about this issue, which is not useful for the most users.

As a "peace of mind" workaround, *users* can simply set the environment variable `_R_S3_METHOD_REGISTRATION_NOTE_OVERWRITES_` to [one of `0`, `no` or `false`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2b097f094444a02b6096f17c9e812a494a6b27a3/src/library/base/R/namespace.R#L1701-L1702) *before* loading any of the affected packages:

```r
Sys.setenv(`_R_S3_METHOD_REGISTRATION_NOTE_OVERWRITES_` = "false")
```

Background: There was some instructive conversation about overwriting S3 methods becoming verbose with R 3.6 [over at rlang's GitHub repo](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/669) for anyone interested in more details.

Comment: This works, however I have to use it every time I restart Rstudio. Is there a way to make this permanent?

Comment: Add the line to your [`.Rprofile`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf) file.